# Can someone tell me why one column is aligned right next to the wall of the div box?

Tags: css, text, alignment

I am wondering why all the text appears good, but the one....the one that is formatted with "#text a"?

Here is my attempt for formatting a text: http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/44/

Comment: Put your code in your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `display: block;`:

```
#text a {
    color: #151515;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
}
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/47

Answer (score 0):

Heading elements (`h1`, `h2`, etc.) have different default formatting, compared to `a` elements.

Using a `p` element for paragraphs of text might be more syntactically correct in the example you've given. `a` is *usually* for inline hyperlinks (although HTML5 allows block level elements to be put inside `a` elements. If that's the case, I would still recommend just using a `p` tag inside the `a` tag.)

It might be less of a headache for you if you use elements for the purpose for which they were intended, instead of restyling elements to act like other elements (that's not always the case, but for example, trying to make a `span` act like an `h1` might cause a person more trouble than if the person just uses the `h1` in the first place. Just a suggestion.)

If, however, your specific purpose requires that your `a` acts like your other block level elements in your example, you can simply add `display: block` to `#text a`:

```
#text a {
    // other styles
    display: block;
}
```